# session is being closed after viewing page with non-admin table

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on a template site and everything was just fine till my host provider updated the server to php 5.4. so I think that my problem lies somewhere in php.ini but when I log in to the admin center of the site everything is fine. I have four pages that the sessions work fine with and one page that pulls the products for viewing and editing. I can switch back and forth between the regular pages in the admin center all day long but when I click on ( view/edit ) link it will show the product but when I click any other link after that it kills the session.

outside of php.ini the only other place I could think may be a problem is in my login_session.php that I include to every page in the admin. Here is that page:

```
    <?php 

    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["manager"])){

    header("location:admin_login.php");

    exit();

    } 

    //BE SURE that this manager SESSION value is in fact in the database

    $managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i',"",$_SESSION["id"]);//filter everything but       numbers and letters

    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i',"",$_SESSION["manager"]);//filter   everything but numbers and letters

    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i',"",$_SESSION["password"]);//filter   everything but numbers and letters

    //Run mySQL query to be sure that this person is an admin and that their password   session var equals the database information

    //connect to the mysql database

    include"../storescripts/connect.php";

    $sql = mysqli_query($myConnection,"SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='$managerID' AND   username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");

     //query the person

    //--------MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE-------

    $existCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); //count the row nums

    if($existCount == 0){ //evaluate the count

     echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database. <a   href=\"logout.php\"><strong>BACK TO LOGIN</strong></a>";

    exit();

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I never saw such kind of documentation before

Answer (score 0):

Its is working now. It was in fact a problem with php.ini upgrade. I contacted my host provider and told them the problem and he updated a part of php.ini but he was real vague on what part he updated.